# SQLAlchemy ResultProxy.rowcount not zero when UPDATE has no affected rows

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

We have a MySQL database and we're switching from DB API to SQLAlchemy.  From the documentation, the ResultProxy.rowcount is supposed to report the number of affected rows by an UPDATE statement.

If I execute this query with SQLAlchemy:

```
UPDATE table
SET field =
IF(field < 10, 10, field) WHERE id = 1
```

It will return a rowcount of 1 if there's a matching row, but for any value of "field" (even when greater or equal than 10).  When I executed this query with DB API, it returned the correct number of affected rows (0 when field was greater or equal than 10 and 1 if lower).

That's causing us some troubles because we'll have to first execute a select query to determine if there was a change or not.  Is it a bug in SQLAlchemy?  The documentation clearly states that if should return the number of affected rows, not the number of matching rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No experience with MySQL, but the documentation for [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) reveals:

> For `UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed. If you specify the
>   `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag to `mysql_real_connect()` when connecting to
>   `mysqld`, the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that
>   is, matched by the WHERE clause.

So, depending on how the connection is configured, the result can be one of two:

- number of "found" rows (those that matched the `WHERE` clause)
- number of actually "updated" rows (where the value in at least one column has changed)

In regards to relationship to sqlalchemy, I am not sure if it is a bug or just the documentation needs to be updated with a better wording.
In any case, you can solve the problem by re-writing your `SQL` statement with another semantically the same:

```
UPDATE  table
SET     field = 10
WHERE   id = 1
    AND field < 10
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever workaround!  I was so focused on finding out why SQLAlchemy returned this value that I didn't even think about this.

But still, it looks like a bug and I'll contact SQLAlchemy about it.